# How could I change ringer status with an app in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Everything I've read says this isn't an option with the currently available APIs outside of unlocked phones.  But then I saw this app in the market http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/6813ea1f-8d71-4ad5-a6d2-f80c193c6ac9

Somehow this guy/gal has figured out how to change the phone to vibrate based on wifi so does anyone have an idea how to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my short investigation, it appears to be a fake application, that does not actually do anything. There are no open APIs that would allow you to switch the phone ring style directly.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  I had read the same things as you, I just was hoping there might be a clever work around that app developer had come across.